# Content-length not read

Tags: iphone, xcode, curl, content-length

I have a problem trying to get the size of an image before downloading it.

I am trying to read the headers of image files from a remote server in Xcode. The link to a sample image is here: http://www.iseivijosdaile.lt/iPadWS/images/thumbnail_1195165011LIDF-0130.png

Terminal command

```
curl --head http://www.iseivijosdaile.lt/iPadWS/images/thumbnail_1195165011LIDF-0130.png
```

returns Content-Length: 125803

While the following

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
        NSLog([dictionary description]);
    }
}
```

does not contain the field Content-Length.

Why is this happenning and how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Its because Content-Length for a `NSURLResponse *` is not stored with the rest of the header fields, but in it's own field:

```
[httpResponse expectedContentLength];
```

Comment: From Apple: A dictionary containing all the HTTP header fields of the receiver. By examining this dictionary clients can see the “raw” header information returned by the HTTP server.

Comment: @bolshas It have got the same problem. I added 

    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"" forKey:@"Accept-Encoding"]];

to fix it, and it works now

Comment: 8  years later... that worked for me too, but I wish I understood better why!